# Como ler um arquivo txt local em Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Olá sou iniciante no Javascript e estou assistindo alguns vídeos no youtube sobre reduce e a minha dúvida é, no vídeo ele coloca um código no topo do arquivo.

```
import fs from 'fs'
```

Porém quando coloco esse código no meu js e tento compilar (node nome-do-arquivo.js) ele dá erro na compilação:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import fs from 'fs'
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:425:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:146:9)
```

Como devo fazer para conseguir importar esse módulo para tratar um txt no meu código.

Desculpem aí se pode ser algo muito óbvio, mas realmente não estou conseguindo.

Link do vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DMolJ2FrNY&list=PL0zVEGEvSaeEd9hlmCXrk5yUyqUag-n84&index=4

Comment: Como você está executando este código ?

Comment: a principio, você deveria usar `require` e não `import`, i.e.: `var fs = require('fs');` - você poderia [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/221226/edit) sua pergunta e incluir o link para o tutorial/vídeo?

Comment: Quando diz : "Como ler um arquivo txt local em Javascript" o que vc quer dizer? O que você gostaria de fazer?  Qual o `path` do arquivo?

Comment: Qual é a versão do Node que estás a usar? talvez ainda não suporte `import`. Faz upgrade para a versão 8.

Comment: @PedroNeri através do terminal com o node.

Comment: @blogueira Adicionei o vídeo que mencionei na pergunta.

Comment: @MagicHat Quero tratar um arquivo 'txt' que está na pasta local através de functions até transformá-lo em um json.

Comment: dei uma olhada no vídeo - ele cita o uso do `require` no momento em que ele escreve o `import` (eu tentaria fazer "à maneira antiga" e usar `require` - você fez isso?) - de qualquer modo, ele parece **também** estar usando [babel](https://babeljs.io/) que "transpila" o código e permite o uso de `import` quando ele não está disponível

Comment: @blogueira eu usei o require e deu certo ;) Porém gostaria de entender como ele fez dessa forma, de qualquer maneira obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Poste uma resposta do problema para que a pergunta não fique "perdida" por aí como "pergunta sem resposta", e depois marque ela como "resposta correta".

Comment: O nodejs por padrão usa o require em vez do import.
´const fs = require('fs')´

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 2):

Para requerer um módulo no `Node` utilize o `require`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

E para ler o arquivo utilize a função [`readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) ou [`readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options):

```
fs.readFile('<diretório>', (err, data) => {
  // => null, <data>
});

fs.readFileSync('<diretório>');
```